# Function that returns 2 or more dfs - how to call it in the main() function?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a series of functions and then I would like to call them all in the main() function. I have been able to do that except I'm not sure how to handle a function that returns two or more data frames. How do you call this function in the main() function? Thanks for the help!

My guess is something like:

```
df, df2 = operation_one(df, df2)
```

> > > 

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def loader():

    df = pd.read_excel('file_example.xlsx')
    return df


def clean_data(df):

    del df['column_7']
    return df


def operation_one(df):

    del df['column_12']

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['Blue', 'Yellow'], 'Size': ['big', 'small']})
    
    return df, df2


def main():

    df = loader()
    df = clean_data(df)
    df = operation_one(df)

    df, df2 = operation_one(df, df2)

    with pd.ExcelWriter("file.xlsx") as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='first' , index=False)
        df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='second' , index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I don't see the problem in your code

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df2' referenced before assignment referring to the line in main()  df, df2 = operation_one(df, df2)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in assigning the return value but in the fact that the parameter df2 passed to the function has been never assigned.  I assume one of the "df =" assignments farther up should have been "df2 =".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `operation_one` function to receive `df2` since you are giving it a new value:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def loader():

    df = pd.read_excel('file_example.xlsx')
    return df


def clean_data(df):

    del df['column_7']
    return df


def operation_one(df):

    del df['column_12']

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ['Blue', 'Yellow'], 'Size': ['big', 'small']})
    
    return df, df2


def main():

    df = loader()
    df = clean_data(df)
   
    df, df2 = operation_one(df)

    with pd.ExcelWriter("file.xlsx") as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='first' , index=False)
        df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='second' , index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```